# javascript - Do additional arguments in a function affect it?

Tags: javascript

```
function a() { alert('"A" is called.'); }
var b = function() { alert('"B" is called.'); }

a(true);
a(false);
a();

b(true);
b(false);
b();
```

The above code creates 3 alerts saying that "A" is called, and then another 3 alerts are created, saying that "B" is called. <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYwH3/)</kbd>

I would like to know, in Javascript, do additional arguments in a function affect the function in any way?

Comment: No it doesn't, they are just ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In fact you can also define a function:

```
var x = function(y) {
  alert("'X' is called with " + y);
}
```

and call it as `x()` without any parameters at all.

It will create an alert saying `'X' was called with undefined`.

Inside functions you have access to its arguments in an array-like object called `arguments`.

See [the "arguments" docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for more details.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for when arguments aren't specified. He wants to know what happens to them if they are run through the function, regardless of whether they are requested.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, all variables passed to a function are optional. They will just be undefined. However, in your example, you have not put any variables in the brackets. If you want true/false to be passed to the function you will need to define it as "function a(b) {" with b being the variable you want to pass. Otherwise your boolean is ignored and the function just runs normally and ignores it.